# Choose without pressing enter

Tags: batch-file

I want to change the way the user selects options in my batch program. I would like to make it without pressing enter. Just press number to choose . Could you please help me ? Thank you so much ! :)

Now it is like this.

```
echo    (7)  Main page                                                       
echo    (8)  Go back

set /p "o=Your Choice, %user% ? : "

if %o% == 7 goto MAIN

if %o% == 8 goto BACK

If not %o% == 7 goto ONLY

If not %o% == 8 goto ONLY
```

Comment: Try this thread
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256692/get-user-input-without-pressing-enter)

Comment: Thank you so much , but for me it is still hard to understand it . Could somebody please make an example on my code ? i have a numbers from 1 to 20. Thank you so much .

Comment: Instead of numbers, use letters A...T with the `choice` command (up to 26 choices - make it case sensitive for 52 choices, add numbers for up to 62 choices)

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages have a way to add listeners to certain keys when they are pressed, released, or activated. Listener's will be a function that you can add the code to 'activate' the enter key. I am not familiar with the code you've provided and because there are no tags, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much , but for me it is still hard to understand it . Could somebody please make an example on my code ? i have a numbers from 1 to 20. Thank you so much .